# Vuzix sdk loading error cvc-elt.1.a cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk: sdk-addon'

Tags: android-studio, sdk, vuzix

I am trying to load the SDK for Vuzix through the SDK manager in Android Studio but for some reason it will not display the downloads in 'SDK platforms' and 'SDK tools'.

In the 'SDK update sites' tab next to the Vuzix link I added there is a red exclamation point that displays " cvc-elt.1.a cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk: sdk-addon' " when hovered over.

I am new to SDK's and have no idea what to do for this error. I've downloaded the android SDK's and sources for 26,25,24, and 23 thinking it could help but the error still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the error means but I solved it by connecting to my hotspot instead of my work network.
So my guess is it was a firewall issue or something, if anyone else has this error.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the parser does not know the namespace. I tried it on Win7 and android studio 2.3.3 with the same result.

I tried it without the namespace or running android studio with oracle sdk. Both failed.

At the moment I try to run it on a virtual linux machine. Android Studio 2.3.3 will parse the addon xml file and download the files.

- On Win7 I installed them manually, but they were not really integrated into to system and I stucked when I wanted to use the barcode SDK. maybe I am able some day to add simply this jar lib -

On a first look using linux seems to be the solution. But than I run into problems with the case sensitve file system. The vuzix SDK seems to need a linux system on a case insensitve file system.

*facepalm* and I am quite sure that i will fail at all. On linux a simple GUI compiles only against API 26 without errors.

Comment: Uh, after days of failing its up and running. I don't know why, but it is running. I installed the latest OpenJDK 8, downloaded the m300-addon.xml and the following schema [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/repository/sdk-addon-07.xsd) saved it in the main folder of the android sdk. Tried to refernce the schema in the local xml and after some problems suddenly the remote addon was parsed successfully. Local one is still failing, but who cares ;).